# Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty(), a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a,all()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I'm trying to write a code that takes certain (optional) inputs from a .csv file and outputs based on which criteria (inputs) have been given and which have not. I managed to get the code to take optional inputs but I want the program to take certain outputs from certain rows of the file (for example, variable w is the name of the business, I want it to read only that specified row from the .csv and ignore every other, same for every other criteria) so I tried something, here's the code:

```
#link CSV
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Small businesses.csv',encoding='latin1')

    print(df.to_string()) 
   #Take input
w=str(input('enter name here'))
x=str(input('enter field here'))
y=str(input('enter desired operation size here'))
z=str(input('enter preferred mode of service here'))
#refine output
#to revert what you did if it doesn't work, remove the df statements and convert
#every second if back to elif 
if df.iloc[1,4]:
 if x == "":
    print (y + z)
or df.iloc[1,7]:
 if y == "":
    print (x + z)
or df.iloc[1,11]:
 if z == "":
    print (x + y)
or df.iloc[[1,4],[1,7]]:
 if x == "" and y == "":
    print(z)
or df.iloc[[1,4],[1,11]]:
 if x == "" and z == "":
    print(y)
or df.iloc[[1,7],[1,11]]:
    if y == "" and z == "":
     print(x)
or df.iloc[[1,1]]:
 if w == "":
    print ("accoridng to other guidelines, we find:")
```

I know the code is wrong but I just don't know how to fix it since I'm new to programming, I got this error: "Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty(), a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a,all()"
Any fixes? Thank you

*edit*:
For all the people asking me to paste a portion of the .csv to help, here it is:
[small business.csv screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znppd.png)

Here's the full error from the kernel:
File "C:\Users\ASUS\untitled2.py", line 29, in 
if df.iloc[[1,4],[1,7]]:

File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1330, in **nonzero**
f"The truth value of a {type(self).**name**} is ambiguous. "

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
(sorry I'm new to this)

Comment: For questions involving an external file, you should paste at least a portion of the file for reference. Otherwise anybody attempting to answer can't test their solution. As it stands we have no knowledge of what is inside your `df` and can't offer much advice.

Comment: please paste an example of `Samll businesses.csv` and an example of what you intend output here

Comment: You should show the output error, which would include a pointer to the source of the problem...That being said, I'm assuming it's due to the `df.iloc[[1,4],[1,7]]` type of statements. You realize that the boolean value of a list is ill-defined, yes? Hence the `all` or `any` etc...

Comment: Please in the future post *full* stack trace, not only the last line, and not only in the title. Will make helping you much easier.

Comment: I've just added a portion of the .csv to help, added the full error as well

Comment: If the answer helped you, please accept it and consider upvoting

Answer (score 0):

```
df.iloc[[1,4],[1,11]]
```

and other such statements return a [`pd.series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html), not a Boolean.

In order to evaluate those in an If statement, you have to reduce these multiple values into a single Boolean value using some logic.

Usually, you will want to use [`.any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) or [`.all()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for that.

Comment: Thank you! Although I'm sorry but I'm pretty new to this and have never used either command before (an optional subject in school only teaches you so much lol) can you tell me where/how to use it if you don't mind? Once again thank you!

Comment: @Shash What do you want to know that isn't in the linked docs? Any checks if any value in the vector is truthy, All checks if all are truthy. Not much more to it.